# Is there any simple way to toggle background color in javascript..??

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to javascript.. I want to know if there is any simple way to toggle background color in javascript..

here is the html code

```
<td  style="width:70px;height:70px;background-color:white;" class="white" onclick="place(this,2,1)"></td>
<td  style="width:70px;height:70px;background-color:black;" class="black" onclick="place(this,2,2)"></td>
```

here is the javascript code

```
function place(domObj,row,col){

            var placeQueen=false;


            if(domObj.style.backgroundColor=="black"||domObj.style.backgroundColor=="white")
                domObj.style.backgroundColor="red";



            if(domObj.style.backgroundColor=="red")
                domObj.style.backgroundColor=domObj.className;
}
```

But it seems to be not working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seems to be mixing inline styles and CSS classes, which seems to be unnecessary here...
I'd suggest removing the inline styles and using css classes. Inline styles add duplicate code and makes code unreadable and hard to work with.

here's an article from MDN on [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS).

For the task at hand, You can make use of the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) API for CSS class manipulations.

HTML

```
<td class="white" onclick="place(this)"></td>
<td class="black" onclick="place(this)"></td>
```

CSS

```
.black{
  background:black;
}
.white{
  background:white;
}
.red{
  background:red !important;
}
```

JS

```
function place(domObj) {
  domObj.classList.toggle("red");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7xEw/2/)

*The HTML, CSS and JS is much simpler, readable and easily scalable if you ask me…*

Comment: +1 for a simple working solution that doesn't mention jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

In fact the second `if` should be `else if`:

```
if(domObj.style.backgroundColor=="black"||domObj.style.backgroundColor=="white")
     domObj.style.backgroundColor="red";
else if(domObj.style.backgroundColor=="red")
     domObj.style.backgroundColor=domObj.className;
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/EcPex/)

**NOTE**: You should not use inline-style, just use class, you can toggle the class using the pure javascript `classList.toggle()` ([element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)), if that feature is not supported, you can even try modifying the `className` using some algorithm. And the last, you should use [jQuery](http://jquery.com). Search for it and get started now, it's not time to use pure Javascript today although it's better to learn it first before digging into some framework like `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `else`.  As it is, you're changing the background to red, and then immediately back to black or white (since the second if statement will now be satisfied):

```
function place(domObj,row,col){

            var placeQueen=false;


            if(domObj.style.backgroundColor=="black" || domObj.style.backgroundColor=="white")
                domObj.style.backgroundColor="red";
            else if(domObj.style.backgroundColor=="red")
                domObj.style.backgroundColor=domObj.className;
}
```

Your solution is pretty interesting.  You might want to check out a library like jQuery.  It'll make a lot of stuff like this much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a jQuery solution, you could do something like this:

## CSS

```
.red{ background-color:red;}
.black{ background-color:#000;}
```

## HTML

```
<td  style="width:70px;height:70px;" class="red"></td>
<td  style="width:70px;height:70px;" class="black"></td>
```

## jQuery

```
$(function(){
   $('td.red, td.black').on('click', function(){
        var this_class = $(this).attr('class');
       if(this_class == 'red')
       {
           $(this).removeClass('red');
           $(this).addClass('black');
       }
       else
       {
           $(this).removeClass('black');
           $(this).addClass('red');
       }            
   });
});
```

The jQuery code can be reduced more, but I've kept it simple so that it is understandable and readable.

Note: This would also require that you include the [jQuery](https://jquery.com) library on your page before using it.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9C6Ub/)

Comment: We shouldn't be encouraging jQuery to solve one simple problem.  At the very least, you should provide an alternative solution without jQuery.

Comment: jQuery, while it can be a very useful library, has a syntax all of its own.  It has been creating a generation of javascript programmers who cannot program in javascript without jQuery.  For such a minor issue, it shouldn't merit the use of jQuery imho, however this is just my opinion.  I won't penalize you, because the answer works and the issue with jQuery is a subtle point.

Comment: True, but personally speaking, after learning jQuery life got a lot easier for me. It's not just the lines of code but also how easy it is to understand and implement a certain piece of action/behaviour with jQuery, is what has made me a fan of it

Comment: I won't say jQuery doesn't have its moments, because it cuts a lot of corners when you need to write a professional website, however I do believe we should emphasize pure javascript.