# This as a parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am new to javascript development ..I have seen some come in javascript ..The code is

## html code

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td  style="width:70px;height:70px;background-color:white;" class="white" onclick="place(this,2,1)"></td>

<td  style="width:70px;height:70px;background-color:black;" class="black" onclick="someone(this,2,2)"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

## the js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">





function someone(domobject,number,column){  
  if(domobject.style.backgroundColor=="black"||domobject.style.backgroundColor=="white")
       domobject.style.backgroundColor="red";
  else if(domobject.style.backgroundColor=="red")
       domobject.style.backgroundColor=domobject.className;
}
</script>
```

The thing is that

```
  function someone(number,column){  
  if(this.style.backgroundColor=="black"||this.style.backgroundColor=="white")
       this.style.backgroundColor="red";
  else if(this.style.backgroundColor=="red")
       this.style.backgroundColor=this.className;
}
```

when i write the code like this and call it with `onclick="someone(2,2)`..its doesnt work for me..why is it like that..Hope you guys can help me out ..Thanks in advance

Comment: whats the error your getting ? "its doesnt work for me"

Comment: You probably should not be using `onclick=` anyway.

Comment: Because the window is passed as this by default

Comment: But you can write: someone.call(this,2,2)

Comment: when i used the first code and called it with onlclick like  onclick="someone(this,2,2)..it works for me ..but the second option didnt worked

Comment: You should better use the css solution provided to you 3 hours ago : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800492/is-there-any-simple-way-to-toggle-background-color-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the parent.

So:

```
var Bacon = function(){
     this.tasty = true;
     this.burnt = false;
};

var b = new Bacon();
console.log(b.tasty); //True
```

The best place to get your head around this is with this tutorial: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/

Comment: this is not the answer to my qus

Comment: Okay, you are getting the Window object not the dom when you access 'this' btw

Comment: @woverton I think this link might help you understand your problem: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: i need to know why my script doesnt works when i replaced domobject and used this keyword

Comment: Well the 'DOM' and 'window' are different global variables. The DOM is where HTML is kept and 'window' is where javascript variables are stored

Comment: can you tell me why am not getting output when i use the second code